# Fake path is stored in mongodb while uploading image with base64 using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
        Angular:
        I'm trying to upload an image through angular using base64 format but in MongoDB, it stores the fake path i.e 'c://fakepath/filename.jpg' instead of storing  base64 string
        
             onSubmit(): any {
            //     this.url=this.newuserForm.value;
        
            // this.newuserForm.value.file =this.url
            // let d=sessionStorage.getItem('image');
            // this.newuserForm.value.files=d;
        
            // console.log("before fetch"+this.newuserForm.value.file);
        
        
            this.crudService.AddUser(this.newuserForm.value)
              .subscribe((d) => {
                console.log('Data added successfully!');
                console.log(d);
                //  this.url=d.files;
                console.log("new file" + d.file);
        
        
                this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/useraction'))
              }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
        
             // file upload
          onSelectFile(event: any) {
            if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
        
              reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
        
        
              reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
                this.url = event.target.result;
                //store image from base 64 format 
                console.log("my ts file url is " + this.url);
                sessionStorage.setItem('image', this.url)
                this.newuserForm.value.file = this.url;
        
              }
            }
          }
        
        
        Html :
```

Here is the Html file by using I'm trying to upload File

```
            label class="hoverable" for="fileInput">
                    <img  name="image" [src]="url ? url : 'https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png'" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                    <div class="hover-text">Change Image
                      <!-- <img class="camimg" src="assets/cameraicon.jpg" /> -->
                
                    </div>
                    <div class="background"></div>
                  </label>
                  <br/>
                <input id="fileInput" type='file' formControlName="file"  (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
```

CrudeService.ts
This is a crud service file using this I'm trying to call the backend API and backend Model I have taken file type as String
// Add User
AddUser(data: Users): Observable {
let API_URL = `${this.REST_API}/add-user`;
return this.httpClient.post(API_URL, data)
.pipe(
catchError(this.handleError)
)
}

Comment: you are not showing the whole code, how does the crud service look like? what about the mongodb crontroller?

Comment: // Add User
    AddUser(data: Users): Observable<any> {
      let API_URL = `${this.REST_API}/add-user`;
      return this.httpClient.post(API_URL, data)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }